# Lync 2010 API - Suppress Toast and Conversation Window

Tags: lync, lync-2010

I'd like users to benefit from the rich Lync Client and the features it offers.

I'd like a custom exe to sit alongside Lync Client and monitor for new IM conversations.

If an IM conversation is from a UCMA bot (pre defined sipuri) or the IM is of a particular type e.g XML, I would like to suppress the Lync Client toast and conversation window and handle in custom exe.

Is it possible to achieve the above scenario without using Lync Client in UI suppression mode?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the answer is no. You can accept the conversation so the toast would go away, but you'd still have the conversation window around.
1 conversation == 1 conversation window unless you are in UI suppression mode.
You can still "hide" the messages you are sending if you use contexts instead of IMs, but this would anyway require you to have an open conversation window with an extension window too.